# How to find the index of a pointer that points to an element in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, pointers, indexing

So I'm trying to write a method that adds an element to my array. My find_key() method returns a pointer that points to an element that is either equal to or greater than one found in the existing array. Is there a way I can find the index of the element that my pointer from find_key() points to?

Here's what I'm working with so far

```
template<typename K, typename V>
bool MapSet<K,V>::add(Node<K,V> n)
{
  Node<K, V> *ptr = find_key(n.first);
  if (size() == capacity_)
  {
    capacity_ *= 2; // Double capacity
    auto *new_data = new [capacity_]; // New array with double capacity
    copy(ary_, ary_+last_, new_data); // Copy over
    swap(ary_, new_data); // Swap pointers
    delete [] new_data; // Delete old array pointer (old since swapped)
  }
  if (size() == 0)
  {
    ary_[0].first = n.first;
    ary_[0].second = n.second;
    return true;
  }
  else if (ptr == ary_+last_)
  {
    ary_[ptr].first = n.first;
    ary_[ptr].second = n.second;
    return true;
  }
  else if ((*ptr) == n.first)
  {
    return false;
  }
  else if ((*ptr) !== n.first)
  {
    ary_[ptr-1].first == n.first;
    ary_[ptr-1].second == n.second;
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Beware that since you find `ptr` before preforming reallocation, if `ptr` points to an element of `ary_`, it will be danling pointer whenever reallocation occurs. Though now that I've re-read the question, it seems like that's what you might be trying to solve.

Comment: You are probably looking for [std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance).

Comment: @ François Andrieux Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with pointers, you can get the index into the array by simply substracting the pointer to the first element in the array from the found pointer. So

```
Node<V, K>* ptr = ...
size_t index = static_cast<size_t>(ptr - ary_);
```

Should do the trick (If the array is from type `Node<V, K>[]`). In case your class supports iterators, you can also use `std::distance` instead.

Comment: This solution works. But I'd like to point out that pointers meet the requirements for a random access iterator and are compatible with iterator based algorithms such as `std::distance`.

Comment: _"In case your class supports iterators..."_ you misunderstand.  Every pointer to an array element is an iterator.  `std::distance` is _more_ flexible.  Not less.